# leveraging browser caching for images served through CDN

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have written this in my .htaccess file to leverage browser caching:

```
# 480 weeks caching
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

It is working well for files coming from mydomain.com url but the problem is that it does not affect the images coming from CDN URLs which are actually subdomains static.mydomain.com etc.

How can I leverage browser caching for images served through CDN?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using S3? You can add this header in the S3 console for resources you want to cache:

```
CacheControl: max-age=999999
```

Comment: Thanks Emanuel. yes we are using S3 and I could find a way to add this header in individual files. It would be great if you can also tell me how to add this header for the entire bucket.